# RASA NLU overfitting entity extraction

Tags: python, nlp, rasa-nlu, named-entity-recognition, crf

**Rasa version:** 0.1.1

**Python version:** 3.7

**Operating system:** osx

**Issue:**

I am making an application that can pick entities from a grocery list. For the first version I am trying only with a couple of products/brands.

My training data has been generated using chatito and these are the query shapes:

```
%[inventory_count]('training': '0.99', 'testing': '')
    order @[count] @[units?] of @[brand?] @[product]
    @[count] @[units?] @[product] by @[brand]
    @[brand] @[product] is @[count] @[units?]
    add @[brand] @[product] @[count] @[units?]
    @[brand] @[product] @[count] @[units?] on floor
```

The product list is something like this:

```
spinach 5 oz
spinach 5 ounces
spinach 16 oz
spinach 16 ounces
spinach
spinach sixteen ounces
spinach five ounces
gala apples
gala apple
apples
apple
```

The trained model is able to detect all the products in the list above but it is also detecting arbitrary products like this (there can be potential errors in the text and I wanted to test for the negative case):

```
spinach 50 oz
call apples
```

Is this overfitting? What are the possible solutions?

Content of configuration file (config.yml):

```
language: "en"

pipeline:
- name: "tokenizer_whitespace"
- name: "ner_crf"
- name: "intent_featurizer_count_vectors"
- name: "intent_classifier_tensorflow_embedding"
  droprate: 0.5
  epochs: 300
  C2: 0.02
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it indeed seems that the conditional random field focuses to much on single words. In order to fix this, you could provide some examples (e.g. `call apple`) and don't annotate the `apple`, so that the conditional random field is forced to generalize.

I also recommend to update to the latest Rasa version (`1.1.4`) since your version is pretty old. A very useful resource for help is also https://forum.rasa.com .